# How do I check if a checkbox is true in HTML and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, checkbox

I'm making a form to check what you can eat if you are allergic. This is my basic form, but I need to check if a checkbox is checked. I tried this, but it doesn't work. The variebles and the text is in Dutch, but you don't have to pay attention to that. Please help me to check if a checkbox is checked. Thank you!

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Selecteer allergieën</title>
    <h1>Selecteer je allergieën hieronder</h1>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form>
    <label for="pinda">
    <input type="checkbox" id="pinda" value="Pinda's">Pinda's
    </label><br>
    <input type="button" value="Gaan ->" onClick="myFunction()">
    </form>
    <script>
function myFunction(){

var pinda = document.getElementById("pinda").checked;

if(pinda = checked){
alert("Je bent allergisch voor pinda's");

}
}



</body>
</html>
```

One var is left, so you can review the code easily.

Comment: Nothing wrong guys he just forgot to end script tag so function not found error would be coming when he clicks on the button. MoosMas look at my answer I updated it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you have is that you're checking whether an input is checked, which returns a Boolean (`true`/`false`), and then, in the `if` you're assigning the value of an undeclared variable `checked` to the variable `pinda`. What you need to do is:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var pinda = document.getElementById("pinda").checked;

  if (pinda === true) {
    alert("Je bent allergisch voor pinda's");
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="pinda">
    <input type="checkbox" id="pinda" value="Pinda's" />Pinda's
  </label>
  <input type="button" value="Gaan ->" onClick="myFunction()" />
</form>
```

Or, more simply:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var pinda = document.getElementById("pinda").checked;

  if (pinda) {
    alert("Je bent allergisch voor pinda's");
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="pinda">
    <input type="checkbox" id="pinda" value="Pinda's" />Pinda's
  </label>
  <input type="button" value="Gaan ->" onClick="myFunction()" />
</form>
```

Incidentally, I'd suggest binding your event-handlers in JavaScript, rather than in the HTML itself (this allows for unobtrusive JavaScript and easier long-term maintenance):

```js
function myFunction() {
  var pinda = document.getElementById("pinda").checked;

  if (pinda === true) {
    alert("Je bent allergisch voor pinda's");
  }
}

// using document.querySelector to retrieve the element from
// the document that matches the supplied CSS selector:
var button = document.querySelector('form input[type=button]');

// using addEventListener to bind myFunction as the
// click event-handler for the button node:
button.addEventListener('click', myFunction);
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="pinda">
    <input type="checkbox" id="pinda" value="Pinda's" />Pinda's
  </label>
  <input type="button" value="Gaan ->" />
</form>
```

Comment: Or more simply: if (document.getElementById("pinda").checked ) alert("Je bent allergisch voor pinda's"); ?

Comment: @David Thomas     Thanks for you comment, but it still doedn't work. When I check     pinda it and press the button it still doesn't doe antything.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal demonstration to reproduce your issue? With *one* checkbox and *one* alert (literally: just the *minimum* code necessary). @Gael: that's an option too, but I didn't want to reduce it to that form simply because of the OP's apparently-limited (at this stage) experience, although in fairness it's exactly complex.

Comment: @DavidThomas, Didn't know your Dutch was so flawless ;-)

Answer (score 1):

1. Now I got your problem  tag needs to be end like `</script>`.
2. if condition is also now right should be `if(pinda == true)`.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Selecteer allergieën</title>
  <h1>Selecteer je allergieën hieronder</h1>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <label for="pinda">
      <input type="checkbox" id="pinda" value="Pinda's">Pinda's
    </label>
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Gaan ->" onClick="myFunction()">
  </form>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {

      var pinda = document.getElementById("pinda").checked;

      if (pinda === true) {
        alert("Je bent allergisch voor pinda's");

      }
    }
  </script>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but if I run the snippet on stackoverflow it works, but if I paste it into my code it doesn't work. @Jenish Rabadiya